# Perfect Prime $4D$-Cube

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

First, "definition" by the images:

[image: Prime Cube of 1st kind]
    
[image]

Now, define $n$-dimensional **Prime Cube of the $1$st kind** $(b;l_1,l_2,\ldots, l_n)^{-}$ as the set
$$(b;l_1,l_2,\ldots, l_n)^{-} = \Bigl\{ b\cdot l_1^{d_1} \cdot l_2^{d_2}\cdots l_n^{d_n} - 1\Bigr\}_{(d_1,d_2,\ldots,d_n)\in\{0,1\}}\tag{1}$$
of $2^n$ distinct elements, and each such element is prime number ($b,l_1,l_2,\ldots,l_n\in\mathbb{N}$).

Similarly, $n$-dimensional **Prime Cube of the $2$nd kind** $(b;l_1,l_2,\ldots, l_n)^{+}$ is the set
$$(b;l_1,l_2,\ldots, l_n)^{+} = \Bigl\{ b\cdot l_1^{d_1} \cdot l_2^{d_2}\cdots l_n^{d_n} + 1\Bigr\}_{(d_1,d_2,\ldots,d_n)\in\{0,1\}}\tag{2}$$
of $2^n$ distinct prime numbers.

And $n$-dimensional **Perfect Prime Cube** $(b;l_1,l_2,\ldots, l_n)^{*}$ is the set
$$(b;l_1,l_2,\ldots, l_n)^{*} = \Bigl\{ b\cdot l_1^{d_1} \cdot l_2^{d_2}\cdots l_n^{d_n} \pm 1\Bigr\}_{(d_1,d_2,\ldots,d_n)\in\{0,1\}}\tag{3}$$
of $2^{n+1}$ distinct prime numbers (oter words, of $2^n$ distinct prime twins).

Example of **Perfect Prime $3D$-Cube**:
$$(30; 5, 22, 78)^*$$
all the $16$ numbers
$30±1$, $30\cdot 5±1$, $30\cdot 22±1$, $30\cdot 78±1$, $30\cdot 5\cdot 22±1$, $30\cdot 5\cdot 78±1$, $30\cdot 22\cdot 78 ±1$, $30\cdot 5 \cdot 22 \cdot 78±1$
are distinct prime numbers.

It is easy to find examples of  Prime $4D$-Cubes of the $1$st and $2$nd kind:
Prime $4D$-Cube of $1$st kind: $(6; 5, 14, 15, 47)^–$;
Prime $4D$-Cube of $2$nd kind: $(30; 2, 11, 67, 85)^+$.

But I still cannot find example of Perfect Prime $4D$-Cube.
All that I can find is “almost perfect” one with “defect $3$”:
$$(30; 14, 22, 141, 222)^*_{(3)},$$
which generates set of $32$ distinct numbers, but $3$ of them are composite:

$30\cdot 141\cdot 222-1$,   $30\cdot 22\cdot 222 + 1$   and $30\cdot 14\cdot 141\cdot 222 + 1$.

I believe that such Perfect Prime $4D$-Cube exists.
**Question:**  Do such Perfect Prime $4D$-Cube exist? Any examples?

---

**Note:**
Prime $n$-Cubes of the $1$st kind of the form $(b;2,2^2,2^4,\ldots,2^{2^{n-1}})^-$ are also [Cunningham chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cunningham_chain) of the $1$st kind (of length $2^{n}$); 
example: $(19\:099\:920;2,4,16)^-$ is also Cunningham chain of the $1$st kind of length $8$:

$\bigl\{19\:099\:920 \cdot 2^k - 1; \;\;\; k = 0,1,2,\ldots,7\bigr\}$;

Prime $n$-Cubes of the $2$nd kind of the form $(b;2,2^2,2^4,\ldots,2^{2^{n-1}})^+$ are also [Cunningham chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cunningham_chain) of the $2$nd kind (of length $2^{n}$);

 example: $(15\:514\:860;2,4,16)^+$ is also Cunningham chain of the $2$nd kind of length $8$:

$\bigl\{15\:514\:860 \cdot 2^k + 1; \;\;\; k = 0,1,2,\ldots,7\bigr\}$;

Perfect Prime $n$-Cubes of the form $(b;2,2^2,\ldots,2^{2^{n-1}})^*$ are also [Bi-twin chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-twin_chain) (of length $2^{n}$).

Comment: Sets of the form $a + \chi_1b_1 + \cdots + \chi_nb_n$, $\chi_i \in \{0,1\}$, $a,b_i \in \mathbb{N}$, are called **combinatorial cubes**, **affine cubes**, or sometimes **Hilbert cubes**. Your sets are defined differently, but they are clearly related concepts. You may be able to find previous work on your sets by following the literature from those terms.

Comment: @Eric, thank you for info.

Comment: I believe you answered your own question in the note section. Perfect Prime 4D cube of the form $(b;2,4,8,16)$ is a Bi-Twin chain of length 4. The Wikipedia entry you linked to already provides such Bi-Twin chains.

Comment: @Dmitry, I made small mistake in "Note".
The set $(b; 2,2^2,\ldots,2^n)$ contains coinciding elements.
I should write $(b; 2, 2^2, 2^4, \ldots, 2^{2^k})$ instead.
Then Prime Perfect $3D$ cube of the form $(b; 2,4,16)$ is the set of $8$ prime twins: $\{b\pm 1, 2b \pm 1, 4b\pm 1, 8b \pm 1, 16b \pm 1, \ldots, 128b \pm 1\}$ (Bi-Twin chain of length $8$).
And Prime Perfect $4D$ cube of the form $(b; 2,4,16, 256)$ (if exists) contains $16$ prime twins : $$\{b\pm 1, 2b \pm 1, 4b\pm 1, 8b \pm 1, \ldots, 2^{15}b \pm 1\}$$ (hypothetic Bi-Twin chain of length $16$).

Comment: ... since definition of Perfect Prime $n$-cube is the set of $2^{n+1}$ primes (of $2^n$ prime twins) of the form: $$(b; l_1, l_2, \ldots, l_n) = \Bigl\{ b \cdot l_1^{d_1} \cdot l_2^{d_2}\cdots l_n^{d_n} \pm 1 \Bigr\},$$ where $(d_1,d_2,\ldots,d_n) \in \{0,1\}^n,$ and each element of the set is prime number. (I'll extend the description and will fix the "Note" soon).

Comment: @Oleg567 thanks for the clarification. Currently the longest Bi-Twin chain has length 8, so I am afraid a perfect prime 4D cube is out of reach for now.